# Why does ON DELETE CASCADE sometimes take long on Postgres 9?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a few relations between tables that are all related to one 'owner' table. So just for the sake of the example:

- Table Owner with PK id
- Table Parent with PK id and FK owner_id referring to Owner.id, with an index on it, and   `ON DELETE CASCADE`.
- Table Child with PK id and FK parent_id referring to Parent.id, with an index on it, and `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

The Child table is huge (~50 million rows), the Parent table has a few thousand rows, and Owner table is very small (~10 rows).

There are a few other tables related to Owner and Parent, but they are relatively small (a few thousands) and also have indexes on foreign keys, and `ON CASCADE DELETE`.

Sometimes when I delete an Owner row cascading through all deletes (around 12 million child rows and a 1 thousand parent rows) works really fast (a few seconds), but sometimes it takes nearly an hour.

How do I figure out what is causing this? I did `explain` on `delete from child where parent_id in (select id from parent where owner_id = 1)`, where 1 is the id of one of the owner rows (I tried various ids just to make sure) and it is saying that it is using Bitmap Heap Scan -> Bitmap Index Scan and Index Scan. However I am not sure if I am mimicking what is actually done when there is an `ON DELETE CASCADE` trigger. How can I figure out what is causing these huge delays? Could it be that sometimes Postgres prefers to do a Sequential scan (due to the number of rows)?

Inserting the same rows only takes 8 minutes (including application logic and a few thousand transaction commits) so I can't figure out why straight deleting is taking so long.

I am using Postgres 9.1.6

Comment: please try to EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Comment: tried explain analyse on delete from child where parent_id in (select_id from parent where owner_id = 1) and got the same Bitmap Heap Scan -> Bitmap Index etc. Got these costs: (cost=150.01..562757.84 rows=6560827 width=12) (actual time=39.792..39.792 rows=0 loops=1)

Comment: there are terrible wrong statistics - so bitmap index scan is not optimal - please, try to disable bitmap_scan -- "set enable_bitmapscan to off"

Comment: I executed `set enable_bitmapscan to off` and did `explain analyse` again and now it uses `index scan` only. However I tried to delete again and it is still taking ages :(

Comment: can you send explain analyze result?

Comment: `Simulations` is my `Owner` table in the example above. I tried `explain analyse delete from simulations where id=23` and I got this:  `Delete on simulations  (cost=0.00..1.09 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.085..0.085 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on simulations  (cost=0.00..1.09 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.027..0.028 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (id = 23)`

Comment: `Trigger for constraint fkea2050665119326f on simulations: time=27.289 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint fk771f50745119326f on simulations: time=1.151 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint fk345bb885119326f on simulations: time=1.782 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint fkcd71f39b1f318cb9 on appliances: time=2749917.339 calls=15573
 Trigger for constraint fkcd71f39b47181e79 on households: time=5018.331 calls=1000
 Trigger for constraint fk1003f66a28750af on timeslots: time=19.725 calls=1440
 Trigger for constraint fkcd71f39ba28750af on timeslots: time=8384.469 calls=1440
 Total runtime: 2763378.020 ms`

Comment: @PavelStehule I can send you the schema privately if you like, its only 6 simple tables with some indexes and `ON DELETE` triggers.

Comment: @PavelStehule Sent you an email with it, you might want to delete your email from here to avoid spam bots.

Comment: Did you figure a way out of that? I'm having the same problem and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` showed me it used the index but took 3h+ to remove on entry (6130 to go...).

Comment: @Matthieu Unfortunately not. Its been a few years now, but if I remember well, I dropped the indexes and rebuilt them afterwards when I needed to delete such massive amounts of children linked by a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You say sometimes it goes from seconds to hours.  There are a fairly large number of rows to be deleted.  You could be dealing with all sorts of factors ranging from data caching to row locks.  Unfortunately if these are transient conditions it may be hard to track them down when it is not happening.

A few things you should look at initially is whether you can find any patterns. Look at `SELECT * FROM pg_locks` when it happens.  You should also `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity` when the problem occurs to see where locks may be being held.

Comment: There are no locks, no one else is accessing the database. (In fact I sometimes just drop the database to clean out the data instead because deleting it takes so long, and it allows me). Yes there is a large amount of rows, but inserting them takes 8 minutes, so it doesn't make sense that deleting them takes hours. I recently increased the `shared_buffers` and `effective_cache_size` from defaults, and this seemed to have some effect, taking it down to around 20 minutes... better but not sure if its optimal.